# Lumen middleware: redirect()

Tags: php, lumen

## Background

- Lumen 9.x
- LAMP stack

### Problem

I'm attempting to create a middleware, using the tutorial as an example.
The middleware is successfully loading. However, it is not finding the redirect class.

```php
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if ($request->input('age') <= 200) {
            return redirect('home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

When run, this gives the error: `Target class [redirect] does not exist.`

How do I ensure that redirect is loaded during middleware?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's something wrong with your Lumen installation, maybe you've a broken installation?
Try to start with a fresh Lumen installation, you can get started from [here](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/9.x/installation).